# Blender Render Smoke, vs viewport how to match?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

Using the quick smoke option in blender I created blue smoke, [image]

When its disturbed is gets these great hue of color green dark blue and purple mixed in. Yet when I render it loses those properties and resolution

[image]

http://prnt.sc/e6bhpe . the domain has 256 divisions border collision is open, and density is .001 in the behavior tab. How can I match the  blender render to the viewport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I overcame this by rendering in OpenGL. (Top left of 3D window, open "Render" tab and select "OpenGL RenderAnimation")

Comment: When you render in opengl it tends to capture all your wireframing ect. anyway I can disable that?

Comment: Yes, press N to get to the viewport setting panel.  Open the "Display" tab and tick the "Only Render" box.  That will remove all the lines and stuff.   Make sure no objects are selected either.  (press A)   If any are, the gizmo arrows will be rendered.